# jQuery function only works if I manually resize my window to mobile but not on refresh

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, cross-platform

I have a code snippet where I'm trying to add and remove classes on mobile only and it only works when I manually resize the browser to a mobile window, while when I refresh it, it doesn't work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).on('load, resize', function mobileViewUpdate() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    if (viewportWidth <= 800) {
        $('.header').removeClass('header-transparent');
        $('#navdiv').removeClass('bottom_border');
        $('.navbar-main').addClass('nav-shadow');
        $('#nav-icon').addClass('navbar-toggler-icon2');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with the other answer showing to extract the logic to a method and use it in both place (so as to not proxy logic through the DOM), it is still an option for you to `trigger()` the event on ready as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).on('load, resize', function mobileViewUpdate() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    if (viewportWidth <= 800) {
        $('.header').removeClass('header-transparent');
         $('#navdiv').removeClass('bottom_border');
        $('.navbar-main').addClass('nav-shadow');
     $('#nav-icon').addClass('navbar-toggler-icon2');
    }
  }).trigger('resize');
});
```

Comment: This answer actually ended up working for me. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try extracting the mobileViewUpdate function:

```
function mobileViewUpdate() {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    if (viewportWidth <= 800) {
        $('.header').removeClass('header-transparent');
         $('#navdiv').removeClass('bottom_border');
        $('.navbar-main').addClass('nav-shadow');
     $('#nav-icon').addClass('navbar-toggler-icon2');
    }
}
```

And then call it from `document.ready` and on `resize`, both:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(window).on('resize', mobileViewUpdate);
 mobileViewUpdate();
});
```

This should work. However, I think it would be better to set the meta viewport tag and use media queries instead to adapt the website for mobile.